# Seeing a new error message place holder - is it intentional?

Tags: support, design, error-message

I tried to close a post, when it has 4 close votes already as "close(4)". When I clicked the close button, already the post's status changed to [closed] so it shows a error message.

Previously the error message is displayed in the red colored place holder as below:

> [image: Error message - red color]

But today I see the error message displayed in the white colored place holder as below:

> [image: Error message - white color]

Is the UI design for error messages are changed or it leaked from any other CSS change?

**UPDATE:**

Again I tried the same scenario for a question, it is a "on hold" question and seeing the red colored place holder.

> [image: on hold post]

So on some cases only the new UI is displayed.